# jquery.validate func improper once validateions given in class

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

**Only last element which is given as required is validated [Other elements are not validated while form submission]**

```
$().ready(function(){
    $("#feed").validate();
});
```

**Form:**

```
<form name="feed" id="feed" action="feed.php">                                                              
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="primaryTable" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td><label>Name</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="inputField {required: true}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Email</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="inputField {required: true}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Title</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="inputField {required: true}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

If there is any wrong in usage please notify me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `name` attribute for your `inputs` to be picked up by the validator (I would recommend specifying `id` as well and using the `for` attribute on labels).  Also, you should just use `class="required"` to designate a form field as required:

```
<form name="feed" id="feed" action="feed.php">                                 
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="primaryTable" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td><label>Name</label></td>
        <td><input name="name" type="text" class="required" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Email</label></td>
        <td><input name="email" type="text" class="required" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Title</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="title" class="required" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```